# Declaring a Scalar Variable when using SQLDataSouce

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

My application consists of a GridView, which allows the user to edit, update, and insert data related to auto parts via a SqlDataSource control.  When a user enters a part, the part is available for all users to see and I only want users to see the auto part(s) he or she entered.

The application is accessible via a login page, which captures each user’s company_ guid and stores it in a session, the user‘s company_guid is also captured/ inserted into the table of database along with the part info submitted:

**…Code behind**:

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

  'initialized companyGuid to the session variable, which is captured/stored via the log-in pg
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            companyGuid = Session("numrecord").ToString
        Else
            companyGuid = Session("numrecord").ToString
        End If
    End Sub
```

**...My SqlDataSource is set up like so**:

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource OnInserting="On_Inserting" 
    ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ShipperNotificationConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Part] WHERE Company_guid=@companyguid "
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE Part SET Part_Name=@Part_Name,
    Part_Desc=@Part_Desc, Active=@Active, UpdateDate=@UpdateDate, UpdateBy=@UpdateBy  
    WHERE Part_ID=@Part_ID" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT Part (Company_guid,Part_Name,Part_Desc,Active,UpdateDate,UpdateBy)
            VALUES (@companyguid,@Part_Name,@Part_Desc,@Active,@UpdateDate,@UpdateBy)"          
   runat="server">

   <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="companyguid" SessionField="companyguid" Type="String" />
   </SelectParameters>

   <InsertParameters>
   <asp:SessionParameter Name="companyguid" SessionField="companyguid" Type="String" />
</InsertParameters>
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**...code behind - Event Handler:**

```
Protected Sub On_selectedIndex(ByVal sender As [Object], ByVal e As SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs)
        e.Command.Parameters("@companyguid").Value = Session("numrecord").ToString
    End Sub
```

**…this is the SQL test query:**

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Part
WHERE company_guid = '19595A5C-98B9-4F5E-84F9-0000000'
```

…How do I setup the select statement in my SqlDataSource so that the user only see’s the parts he or she entered? In the SqlDataSource -  SelectCommand, I tried the following:

```vb
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Part] WHERE company_guid = @company_guid"
```

…and received the error - Must declare the scalar variable "@company_guid".
Could I please get some guidance?

Comment: `SqlDatasource` sucks. Not designed for more complex things. You need to add parameter to your Select command.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have setup you `SelectParamters` as below which takes session field named `companyguid` which I don't find in your code but rather it's declared as `@companyguid`

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="companyguid" SessionField="companyguid" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Do change your `PageLoad` like below

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Session("companyguid") = Session("numrecord").ToString
End Sub
```

Or change you select parameter to directly use `SessionField="numrecord"`.

And it's better to set a `DefaultValue="your default company gui id"` for the `<asp:SessionParameter` so it populates the gridview with the default data if the session value is not set for whatever reason. And your SessionParameter becomes

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="companyguid" SessionField="companyguid" DefaultValue="19595A5C-98B9-4F5E-84F9-0000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you specify the placeholder @company_guid on the SELECT quert, you need to create the relative SelectParameter, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters(v=vs.110).aspx).
Depending on where you can take the value from, you've to use the right type of Parameter.

Since you're using session, you can try the [SessionParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Here is the complete list of Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter(v=vs.110).aspx) type you can apply.

Comment: Attn Alpi Alessandro ...Thanks for the source, I added a SelectParameters to the SqlDataSource control along with an event handler to initialize the @companyguid to the session variable (please see edits above), I get a blank grid though. Any further suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks again